# How to read a video with gridfs-stream?

Tags: mongoose, gridfs-stream

I'm using **mongoose** with **gridfs-stream** to store files, images, audios, and videos.

The problem is when **I select another position/time** in the video, is stopped, the same happens when I play any song.

Someone can help me?

This is my code:

```
exports.readById = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.modelName._id;

    gfs.findOne({
        _id: id
    }, function(err, file) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                err: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        }
        if (!file) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                err: 'No se encontró el registro especificado.'
            });
        }

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
            'Content-Length': file.length,
            'Content-Type': file.contentType
        });

        var readStream = gfs.createReadStream({
            _id: file._id
        });

        readStream.on('error', function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    err: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            }
        });

        readStream.pipe(res);
    });
};
```

Comment: You probably need to process range requests (perhaps using [`express-range`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-range)) combined with reading partial data from GridFS (using [the `range` option](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream#createreadstream)).

Comment: I found a solution without using `express-range` module, but you're right, I needed to use the `range` option, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is necessary to use the [`range`](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream#createreadstream) option, it allows us to select another position in the video and play it. In other words, making a request to the server so that the server responds with the data we need.

Here is the complete code, I hope they serve someone.

I found the example [here](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream/issues/41#issuecomment-76353372).

```
exports.readById = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.modelName._id;

    gfs.findOne({
        _id: id
    }, function(err, file) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                err: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        }
        if (!file) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                err: 'No se encontró el registro especificado.'
            });
        }

        if (req.headers['range']) {
            var parts = req.headers['range'].replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
            var partialstart = parts[0];
            var partialend = parts[1];

            var start = parseInt(partialstart, 10);
            var end = partialend ? parseInt(partialend, 10) : file.length - 1;
            var chunksize = (end - start) + 1;

            res.writeHead(206, {
                'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
                'Content-Length': chunksize,
                'Content-Range': 'bytes ' + start + '-' + end + '/' + file.length,
                'Content-Type': file.contentType
            });

            gfs.createReadStream({
                _id: file._id,
                range: {
                    startPos: start,
                    endPos: end
                }
            }).pipe(res);
        } else {
            res.header('Content-Length', file.length);
            res.header('Content-Type', file.contentType);

            gfs.createReadStream({
                _id: file._id
            }).pipe(res);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Under what circumstances is 'req.headers['range']' true? Do I need a really large file for that?

Comment: When used in a <video> tag. The browser will enable "streaming" behavior.